# CSS working in IE - Not any other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to utilize David DeSandro's Masonry plugin (http://masonry.desandro.com/) on my website.  Upon following the instructions the best I can - the site appears to work well in IE but not in any other browser.

The html (javascript) within my default.master.tpl in my custom theme for a Vanilla forum:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/themes/danca/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".DataList").masonry();
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

I've added the {literal} bc it's a .tpl file.  This is just the bottom portion and the whole .tpl file lays out the format of the webpage including #Body #Content, etc.

The CSS:

```
#Body {
    width: 960px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 15px auto 55px;
}

.Discussions.index .Item {
    width: 307px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This masonry plugin is under the container `.DataList` and grouped according to items `.Item`

My practice website is: http://idenitties.com/

Comment: RMJ, they look the same to me. Can you be more specific about what is breaking?

Comment: each .Item in other browsers adjusts the height as far as the text goes, however it does not adjust the height for images within, cutting them off.  In IE it does adjust for everything for some reason

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle instead of just a link to your site?

Comment: There's a first...works in IE, breaks in others....bass ackwards if you ask me :)

Comment: I hear ya - no clue why

Comment: You have errors in your HTML, such as duplicate IDs. Now different browsers respond differently to errors, so I'm not surprised that you get different results in this case. Correct the errors. And you will need to decide if it's HTML5 or XHTML1. Those languages have different syntaxes and different MIME types and you cannot mix them. As it is now, the document is neither valid XML nor valid HTML5.